# Jquery Datepicker plugin value attribute not working

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, datetimepicker

So I am using Coldfusion to develop my project and I have a calendar for the user to select the date that he wants in order to see the reservations for that day.

I have this in coldfusion where RDC is a date that is coming from a form:

```
<cfif IsDefined("RDC")>
     <cfset data = #DateFormat(RDC,"yyyy-mm-dd")#>
<cfelse>
       <cfset data = #DateFormat(Now(),"yyyy-mm-dd")#>
</cfif>
```

Then I have this,

```
<input id="RDC" name="RDC" class="form-control">
```

And in jquery:

```
<script>
         jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('pt');

         jQuery('#RDC').datetimepicker({
                 i18n:{
                  pt:{
                   months:[
                    'Janeiro','Fevereiro','Mar&ccedil;o','Abril',
                    'Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto',
                    'Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro',
                   ],
                   dayOfWeek:[
                    "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", 
                    "Sex", "Sab", "Dom.",
                   ]
                  }
                 },
                 timepicker:false,
                 format:'d-m-Y',
                 value:'#data#'
          });
    </script>
```

So I want to use the variable data defined in coldfusion, but when I try to pass that value to the jquery datetimepicker function (in the value attribute), it always shows today's date.
Can someone help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing to do with the issue, but you don't need any pound signs around the DateFormat(), use:  `<cfset data = DateFormat(Now(),"yyyy-mm-dd")>` Also, consider using `structKeyExists()` instead of `IsDefined`. StructKeyExists is more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work!
Simply added #RDC# to the value of input:

```
<input id="RDC" name="RDC" class="form-control" value="#RDC#">
```

And removed the value property from

```
jQuery('#RDC').datetimepicker({});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**

Wrap the value in

```
value:'<cfoutput>#data#</cfoutput>
```

**Step 2**

Verify that the HTML that is being generated what you are expecting

**Caution**

It will be tempting to wrap the entire `<script>`. If you do that

```
jQuery('#RDC').datetimepicker({
...
```

must become

```
jQuery('##RDC').datetimepicker({
...
```

Comment: If I do the <cfoutput>#data#</cfoutput> in the coldfusion part of the code just for testing purposes, it gives me the correct date. But the date that appears on the calendar is always today's date. Puting-> value:'<cfoutput>#data#</cfoutput> in the javascript code doesn't change anything.